key combo then shift+enter started launching apps recently
I noticed in the past week that some random key combos started launching Apple apps (like the App Store, iMovie, and GarageBand) and it's really annoying. After experimenting I figured out that hitting a then p then shift+return launches the App Store. I'll abbreviate this as a -> p -> shift+return. Similarly, hitting i -> m -> shift+return launches iMovie, g -> b -> shift+return launches GarageBand.
Question: What is the name of this feature and how do I turn it off?
macOS Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
I've checked Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts and didn't find anything that'd enable this behavior. The only app I have running that is handling keyboard inputs is Rectangle.

Does this also happen with another user? You could also try resetting your keyboard shortcuts both in System Settings (System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Reset Defaults) and Rectangle (Settings > gear icon > Reset Default Shortcuts & Snap Areas)

@Thinkr after restarting the computer I can no longer reproduce this. Still have no idea what triggered it.

Well, glad you got it fixed ;)
